# Aurelia cancel a specific request

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to cancel a specific request? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446271/aurelia-httpclient-cancel-requests) to cancel request, but what if i have more than one request, how can i be sure that im not canceling the wrong request? Is there a way to cancel a specific request?

Currently it works like this:

```
async getEmployeeListBySearchword(searchword: string): Promise<IMember[]> {
    try {
        const response = await this.get(`employees/${decodeURIComponent(searchword)}`);
        return JSON.parse(response['response']) as Promise<IMember[]>;
    }catch(e){
        if(e.responseType != "abort") {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

cancelRequest(){
    if(AbortableHttpService.http){
        AbortableHttpService.http['pendingRequests'].forEach(request =>{
            request.abort();
        });
    }
}
```

The http setup code is wrapped into a class named AbortableHttpService, it creates the HttpClient and configures it and hides some of the boilerplate code for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is documented or not, but in the aurelia-http-client source code, I see that a `cancel`/`abort` function is added to the promise you receive when making a request.

So calling either `response.cancel()` or `response.abort()` should work.